# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic for the below mentioned query

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle11g, jsp-tags

PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("update cart set address = ?,city =?,state=?,country=?,mobileNumber=?,orderDate=SYSDATE,deliveryDate= orderDate + INTERVAL '10' DAY ,paymentMethod = ?,transactionId = ?,status=? where email = ? and address is NULL");

orderDate & deliveryDate has varchar(100) datatype in db.

Comment: Why would your date columns have a varchar type?  To get rid of the error, you will need to convert the date into a string.

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of the returned value for SYSDATE is DATE. As orderDate & deliveryDate is varchar(100) datatype, you need to use TO_CHAR() to convert it.
use something like below

```
update cart set address = ?,city =?,state=?,country=?,mobileNumber=?,
orderDate=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
deliveryDate= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + INTERVAL '10' DAY,'yyyy/mm/dd') , 
paymentMethod = ?,transactionId = ?,status=? where email = ? and address is 
NULL");
```